# Error when i deploying Laravel project on free host (000webhostapp.com)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

When I deploying my Laravel project on free host called **000webhostapp.com**,
I got this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from `posts`
>   order by `created_at` desc limit 10)

I tried by creating a database there and also I connected with phpmyadmin.

My config/database.php file is :

```
    <?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Database Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
    | to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
    | you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Database Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
    | Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
    | supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
    |
    |
    | All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
    | so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
    | choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => 'DB_HOST', 'localhost',
            'database' => 'DB_DATABASE', 'id5155399_laravel',
            'username' => 'DB_USERNAME', 'id5155399_victorhugoe',
            'password' => 'DB_PASSWORD', 'ay942006',
            'unix_socket' => 'DB_SOCKET', '',
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],

        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Migration Repository Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
    | your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
    | the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
    |
    */

    'migrations' => 'migrations',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Redis Databases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
    | provides a richer set of commands than a typical key-value systems
    | such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
    |
    */

    'redis' => [

        'client' => 'predis',

        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ],

    ],

];
```

And my .env file is :

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:vSPcSzSYn5vSsZ0m5caAdG7QSGNltPbsHe/6a8tmWms=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=id5155399_laravel
DB_USERNAME=id5155399_victorhugo
DB_PASSWORD=*******

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
```

If someone can address my problem, you welcome.
Thanks

Comment: The given error seems to refer to a closed host:port combination. You are trying to connect to a port on a server that isn't actually open for connections, hence the error 'Connection refused'. Check the details from your hosting provider on what they expect you to use for connecting.

Comment: @KarlViiburg... I used a host: localhost and the port: 3306. Do you think it is not correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the following

```
'mysql' => [
   'driver' => 'mysql',
   'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
   'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
   'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', ''),
   'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', ''),
   'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
   'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
   'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
   'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
   'prefix' => '',
   'strict' => true,
   'engine' => null,
        ],
```

and in env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=id5155399_laravel
DB_USERNAME=id5155399_victorhugo
DB_PASSWORD=ay942006
```

Comment: What is your website link?

Comment: Remove the port and check if it works! i have updated the code

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from `posts` order by `created_at` desc limit 10)

Comment: Your database seems to be empty or missing posts table. Please migrate your database. Free hosting does not provide you a command line interface. You can download the database from your localhost as sql and upload it to 000webhost via phpMyAdmin. And please make proper corrections to your config/database.php  if you are using env file

Comment: I already did it that you suggested. I didn't know where is it the problem? may be a simple thing that makes this error

Comment: Update the question with your new config/database.php and .env there is some error in your config In your question i see that you are not using .env variables and using credentials directly so use localhost instead of 127.0.0.1 or change it to 'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'), which will utilize the hostname from the .env file where you have mentioned localhost

Comment: I did before. Nothing change

Comment: We will be going in circles. If you do not update your current code in your main question. I'll not be able to assume your code changes

Comment: The error is in your user name id5155399_victorhugoe

Comment: change it to the correct username id5155399_victorhugo

Comment: And change your db password and update the password in your cofig as your password was mentioned in the config here. Just a security precaution to make sure people dont connect to your database

Comment: I did what you suggested, but nothing changed!

Comment: Try creating a new database and user. Change the config/database.php and .env to look exactly like i mentioned in my answer. Use the new credentials only on the env file. Do not modify anything in config/database.php and keep it as it is like i mentioned. If the credentials are correct you shall see the website. I have tested and it is working. Check this https://srikanthgopi.000webhostapp.com/

Comment: Also you will need to add  'options'   => [PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true,] in your config. I shall update the code in a a new answer to make it simple

Comment: I got this error:
Wrong COM_STMT_PREPARE response size. Received 7 (SQL: select * from `posts` order by `created_at` desc limit 10)

Comment: Finally you did it.... thanks a lot bro. but I have simple error
404. That’s an error.
The requested URL was not found on this server.
Like when i open About or Register, I found the above error.

Comment: You're welcome. For that i need to know your folder structure accordingly you will need to change your APP_URL in .env file. You can create a new question and paste the question link here . This question already has huge comments.

Answer (score 0):

config/database.php

```
    'mysql' => [
       'driver' => 'mysql',
       'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
       'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
       'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', ''),
       'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', ''),
       'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
       'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
       'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
       'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
       'prefix' => '',
       'strict' => true,
       'engine' => null,
       'options'=> [PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true,]
            ],
```

and in env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=id5155399_laravel
DB_USERNAME=id5155399_victorhugo
DB_PASSWORD=ay942006
```

Just copy paste from here and let me know if it works!

And in your PagesController.php you can change

```
$posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(10)->get();
```

to

```
$posts = Post::latest()->limit(10)->get();
```